# object Object error in SPfx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, react, office-ui-fabric-react

Trying below code to read Site column but getting  value as [object Object] `OnClick` Function:

`onClick={()=>{this.Funnel(items.SiteColumn)}}`

Complete function code:

```
              public render(): React.ReactElement<IAutomationProps> 
              {
                return (
                  <div style={divStyle} >
                    {this.state.items.map((items,key)=>

            {
              return(
                  <DocumentCard
                    aria-label={items.RatingCount} styles={cardStyles} 
                   
                    onClick={()=>{this.Funnel(items.SiteColumn)}}
                  >.
                    <DocumentCardImage height={150} imageFit={ImageFit.cover} imageSrc={items.Picture? items.Picture["Url"] : ''} />
                    <DocumentCardDetails>
                      <DocumentCardTitle title={items.Title} shouldTruncate />
                       <label >{items.RatingCount}</label>
                    </DocumentCardDetails>
                  </DocumentCard> );
                  
                  })}
                </div>
                );
```

Comment: What is stored inside `items`? from where you want to read the site column?

Comment: items:data.d.result   from rest api and site column is Choice column, Checkboxes(allow multiple selections)

Comment: What is the internal name of your column? and value you are getting in `this.Funnel()` function?

Comment: Internal name of column is "Product_x0020_Catalogue" and this.Funnel is function where i have to use this

Comment: tried that but getting [object,object]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110207/discussion-between-kumar-and-ganesh-sanap).

Comment: Try using `items.Product_x0020_Catalogue.results` to get the array of multiple selected choice values.

Comment: Is it working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple selection choice column will be returned in following JSON format while using SharePoint REST API:

```
"Product_x0020_Catalogue": {
    "__metadata": {
        "type": "Collection(Edm.String)"
    },
    "results": [
        "Enter Choice #1",
        "Enter Choice #2"
    ]
}
```

So you need to use `items.Product_x0020_Catalogue.results` to  get the array of multiple selected choice values.